# Using pdh functions to get multiple performance counters

Tags: visual-c++, performancecounter

Please have a look on the below code(taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373228%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pdh.h>
#include <pdhmsg.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "pdh.lib")

CONST PWSTR COUNTER_PATH    = L"\\Processor(0)\\% Processor Time";
CONST ULONG SAMPLE_INTERVAL_MS = 1000;

void DisplayCommandLineHelp(void)
{
    wprintf(L"The command line must include a valid log file name.\n"); 
}

void wmain(int argc, WCHAR **argv)
{
    HQUERY hQuery = NULL;
    HLOG hLog = NULL;
    PDH_STATUS pdhStatus;
    DWORD dwLogType = PDH_LOG_TYPE_CSV;
    HCOUNTER hCounter;
    DWORD dwCount;

    if (argc != 2) 
    {
        DisplayCommandLineHelp();
        goto cleanup;
    }

    // Open a query object.
    pdhStatus = PdhOpenQuery(NULL, 0, &hQuery);

    if (pdhStatus != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        wprintf(L"PdhOpenQuery failed with 0x%x\n", pdhStatus);
        goto cleanup;
    }

    // Add one counter that will provide the data.
    pdhStatus = PdhAddCounter(hQuery,
        COUNTER_PATH,
        0,
        &hCounter);

    if (pdhStatus != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        wprintf(L"PdhAddCounter failed with 0x%x\n", pdhStatus);
        goto cleanup;
    }

    // Open the log file for write access.
    pdhStatus = PdhOpenLog(argv[1], 
        PDH_LOG_WRITE_ACCESS | PDH_LOG_CREATE_ALWAYS,
        &dwLogType,
        hQuery,
        0, 
        NULL,
        &hLog);

    if (pdhStatus != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        wprintf(L"PdhOpenLog failed with 0x%x\n", pdhStatus);
        goto cleanup;
    }

    // Write 10 records to the log file.
    for (dwCount = 0; dwCount < 10; dwCount++) 
    {
        wprintf(L"Writing record %d\n", dwCount);

        pdhStatus = PdhUpdateLog (hLog, NULL);
        if (ERROR_SUCCESS != pdhStatus)
        {
            wprintf(L"PdhUpdateLog failed with 0x%x\n", pdhStatus);
            goto cleanup;
        }

        // Wait one second between samples for a counter update.
        Sleep(SAMPLE_INTERVAL_MS); 
    }

cleanup:

    // Close the log file.
    if (hLog)
        PdhCloseLog (hLog, 0);

    // Close the query object.
    if (hQuery)
        PdhCloseQuery (hQuery);
}
```

How do I add more counters to collect data, say 10 counters?

If I do it this way,

```
CONST PWSTR COUNTER_PATH    = L"\\Processor(0)\\% Processor Time";
CONST PWSTR COUNTER_PATH1    = L"\\Processor\\% Processor Time";

HQUERY hQuery = NULL;
HQUERY hQuery1 = NULL;

pdhStatus = PdhOpenQuery(NULL, 0, &hQuery);
pdhStatus1 = PdhOpenQuery(NULL, 0, &hQuery1);
```

etc for each counter. This will be tedious as I will need to make changes to the whole code accordingly. Can you please suggest any other way out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `PdhOpenQuery` once, then `PdhAddCounter` as many counters to the query as you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But, how do I get the counters dynamically. For eg, Process(chrome)\ThreadCount , Processs(explorer)\% User Time .

Comment: Yes, I could use that to enumerate all the process. Then, what would be the next step to add these many counters? Can you please elaborate. Thank you so much.

Comment: Then you call `PdhAddCounter` that many times. I'm not sure I understand the nature of the difficulty.

Comment: Can you show me how to add one more counter say 
CONST PWSTR COUNTER_PATH2    = L"\\Processor(1)\\% Processor Time";
to the basic code I mentioned in the question ?

Comment: Right after `PdhAddCounter` call, call `PdhAddCounter` again, with `COUNTER_PATH2` as the second argument.

Comment: Can you please have a look on the above code. I added COUNTER_PATH2. Now, it prints the second counter only. How can I print the first counter also ?
Please go to the "TODO" section of the code. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Use two different `HCOUNTER` variables, one for each counter. Call `PdhGetFormattedCounterValue` twice, once for each counter.

Comment: Note also that you can use [a wildcard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373193.aspx) in the counter name, as in `"\\Processor(*)\\% Processor Time"`. You can then use `PdhGetFormattedCounterArray` to get values for all instances at once.